# Space of Trigonometric polynomial of degree at most n form subalgebra

Tags: real-analysis

I had encountered following in 
Real analysis by  N L Carothers Page 170-172[image]

[image]

From this $T_1$ becomes subalgebra . but if we consider $\sin x\in T_1$ , $\sin x.\sin x=\sin^2 x\notin T_1$ so how it becomes subalgebra.

Reference: N L Carothers Page 170-172

Please Help me

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $T_n$ is a subalgebra. $\sin^{2}x$  belongs to $T_2$ (but not to $T_1$).  This is because $\sin^{2}x=\frac {1-\cos (2x)} 2$. What is true is $\cup_n T_n$ is a subalgebra.